# Open Graph meta tags for dynamic pages in Experience Cloud

Tags: community

When linking to pages from social media, the Managed Content image, title and description are not appearing in the link preview. I have added the open graph meta tags to the page headers as described under the "Dynamic SEO Page Properties" section of this article
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_seo_tags.htm&type=5

The link preview is working as expected for the object detail page. I have used the following tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{!Record.Name}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{!Record.ShortDescription__c}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{!Record.CourseImage__c}"/>
```

On the Managed Content detail pages the link preview is **not** working as expected. I have used the following tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{!Content.Body.title}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="{!Content.Body.excerpt}"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{!Content.Body.bannerImage.url}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if your experience cloud guest user profile has access to those fields. If not, they can't be shown.